# WCF service parameter with quotes

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to pass a parameter that includes quotes "[" and "]" over url.
Although I`m encoding the parameter string, I´m getting an error related with "illegal character in the path". If I watch at the path value it does not include the "[" encoded! Any suggestions?

```
string parameter = System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode("naFwi@dipSoKSws[sdoO");
var httpClient = new HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler());
httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:8080/");
var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(string.Format("Service.svc/function/{0}", parameter));
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass parameter values as base64 encoded strings. That way you can be pretty sure your data doesn't corrupt.

```
var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
string parameter = System.Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
```